# Pressing enter key then inputting a text on a single line or condition

Tags: selenium

Inputting a text then pressing the enter key on a single line or using a single statement if possible .

tried separating the input of text and the pressing of the enter key

tried this but is it possible to make it just one statement?

```
WebElement department = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));
        WebElement department1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));


    department.sendKeys("10");
    department1.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a");
```

Code

```
WebElement department = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));

department.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "10");
```

I want to input the 10 first before the keys.control or pressing enter key

Comment: 1. "Pressing enter key then inputting a text"
2 "I want to input the 10 first before the keys.control or pressing enter key" 
Question: what exactly do you want ?

Comment: after inputting text , i want to press enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendKeys` method accepts variable number of arguments of type `CharSequence`

You can use

```
department.sendKeys("10", Keys.ENTER)
```

Or

```
department.sendKeys("10", Keys.RETURN)
```

Selenium will send the key sequence as first argument, followed by second and so on...

[Java Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just send them one by one. (I changed it to python code :) )

```
department = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']")

department.sendKeys("10")
department.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL)
```

Comment: do you know how to make it work? I am kind of new in coding , also dont know much about python. It suggested to add a cast?

Comment: Are you using java to do it? I am sure it is same in java too. Just sendkeys("something") than sendkeys("Keys.Control")